# devise remember_me value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise in my application. When a user goes to my website, if i know that the user had previously visited my website and checked 'Remember Me' while logging in, I want to show ihm a special message. How I do get this **remember me** value from devise in my view? Thanks.

Comment: The question is not quite clear: do you want to know that the `remember-me` flag is set when logging in, or do you want to know a user was automatically logged in, because the `remember-me` flag was set before?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a saved user and wants to know whereas he clicked on the remember_me use the field:

`@user.remember_created_at`

If you have a instantiated user in your controller after the form submission, you can access the value using:

`@user.remember_me`

`remember_me` is a `attr_accessor` in Devise gem, see [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/rememberable.rb#L42). Which means it will not be persisted when saving you user's instance.